# Is none transaction faster than setting @Transactional(readOnly = true) for read methods?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, transactions

If we have a service that only gets data from database via Hibernate, is there any advantage adding the annotation `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` or in this case we shouldn't use any transaction for the methods/service?

Enabling `readOnly=true` informs Hibernate to set FlushMode as NEVER, but if our service does not have all CRUD operations is there any meaning for it?

Does any service that access a repository should be transactional?

Comment: Database engine will create transaction anyway, even if you didn't declare transaction explicitly. So, you can't execute statement without "any transaction".  `readOnly` mode helps to underlaying engines (Hibernate, MySql-InnoDb etc) to avoid overheads and make work more efficient.

Comment: So you say that ever I  execute a sql command I should put a @Transactional?